# How can I split the variable to print out something else between the lines?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have created a script that just shows me my IP. I made it so that theres a "box" around the IP when it gets printed out to the terminal.

The output looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------
||                                                ||
||                inet 10.0.2.15                  ||
||                                                ||
----------------------------------------------------
```

Now I made a script which scans for open Ports, where I would also like to have such a "box" around the Output, but I dont know how to implement it, since theres not always the same amount of opened ports and also because the ports are output on multiple lines and are all stored in just one variable. Which means I can't put those "||" on every line. How can I split the variable into as many strings as there are opened ports and make a box around it whether there are 3 or 50 opened ports?

My code so far:

```
#! /bin/bash

#User input
echo -n 'Enter target-IP: '
read target

#Portscan
ports=$( nmap -sS $target | grep open)

#Output
echo'-------------------------'
echo "$ports"
echo'-------------------------'
```

What I want the output to the terminal to be:

```
----------------------------------------------------
||                                                ||
||    21/tcp open ftp                             ||
||    22/tcp open ssh                             ||
||    23/tcp open telnet                          ||                  
||                                                ||
----------------------------------------------------
```

If anything is unclear just ask, as I am not sure if I could describe my problem enough well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options of formatting, awk, bash, ... For example (bash)

```
echo "$ports" | while read x ; do
    printf "||        %-20s ||\n" "$x"
done
```